# calculate the sum of values between 2 dates from another data.frame?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames. I want to calculate the sum of all values in data between (between or similar >= <=) the dates in each row of 'date'

```
  data=data.frame(dat1=c('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', 
                   '2021-01-04', '2021-01-10','2021-02-01', 
  '2021-02-19', 
                   '2021-02-20', '2021-05-10','2021-05-15', '2021-05-30', 
                   '2021-06-04', '2021-06-10','2021-06-11', '2021-06-12', 
                   '2021-06-13', '2021-06-14',"2021-06-15"), 
            values=c(34,56,78,32,2,3,5,4,6,9,8,7,1,2,5,4,7) )


   date=data.frame(dat1=c('2021-01-01', '2021-04-05', 
                   '2021-06-04', '2021-06-10'), 
            dat2=c('2021-01-10', '2021-04-16', 
                   '2021-06-09', '2021-06-20'))
```

desired output:

```
date
     dat1       dat2           res
   1 2021-01-01 2021-01-10    200
   2 2021-04-05 2021-04-16     NA
   3 2021-06-04 2021-06-09     8
   4 2021-06-10 2021-06-20     26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with data.table and a for loop.

First load the library, and change your data frames to data tables

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
setDT(date)
```

Then declare the `res` variable as numeric

```
date$res <- numeric()
```

and run a for loop iterating over each one of the rows in the `date` set.

```
for(r in 1:nrow(date)){
    res_vector <- data[dat1>=date[r,]$dat1 & dat1<=date[r,]$dat2, values,]
    date[r,]$res <- ifelse(length(res_vector)>0, sum(res_vector), NA)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For R to interpret the values in your data.frame as dates I usually use the as_date function from the lubridate package. Afterwards it's a indexing exercise along with the sum function.

```
library(lubridate)

date$dat1 <- as_date(date$dat1)
date$dat2 <- as_date(date$dat2)
data$dat1 <- as_date(data$dat1)


date <- cbind(date,data.frame(res = apply(date, 1, function(x)sum(data$values[data$dat1 >= x[1] & data$dat1 <=x[2]]))))
date
```